In book class, how to raise the lowest footnote text to clear the page frame boundary
\documentclass[english,11pt,twosided,openright]{book}

\usepackage[paperheight=240mm,paperwidth=170mm,asymmetric,bindingoffset=12.5mm,left=12.5mm,right=12.5mm,top=8mm,showframe,showcrop]{geometry}
\usepackage[a4,cam,center]{crop} %

\usepackage{fancyhdr,fancyref} %
\usepackage{footnote} %
\usepackage[symbol]{footmisc}

\usepackage{tocbibind} %
\usepackage{footnote} %
\usepackage{hyperref}

\frontmatter

\setlength{\topmargin}{-25.4mm}
\setlength{\headheight}{17.5mm}
\setlength{\headsep}{2.4mm} 
\setlength{\topskip}{6mm}
\setlength{\textheight}{202.5mm}
\setlength{\marginparsep}{0mm}

\fancypagestyle{mainstyle}{
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[CE]{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\color{black}\fontsize{11.15}{15}\selectfont{--\hspace{2.4pt}{\thepage}\hspace{2.4pt}--}}} %

\renewcommand\footrule
{\color{blue}\hrule width \hsize height 0.75pt}

\renewcommand\footnoterule{\vspace*{-3pt} %
{\color{red}\hrule width 0.6\textwidth height 1.25pt} \vspace*{2.6pt}} %

\renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}} %

\renewcommand\footnotesep{10pt} % lifts upper red line - ok

\setlength{\footskip}{12pt}

\begin{document} 

\pagenumbering{arabic} % 1, 2, ...
\setcounter{chapter}{2} %
\setcounter{page}{1}

\chapter{Chapter ONE}

\section{Section ONE}

\clearpage
\pagestyle{mainstyle}

Some text with a footnote\hspace{2.2pt}\footnote{\hspace{4.2pt}What is the source of the line passing throught the page number?}

\vspace{4pt}
Some more text with a footnote\hspace{2.2pt}\footnote{\hspace{4.2pt}Good vertical spacing}

\vspace{4pt}
Yet more text with a footnote\hspace{2.2pt}\footnote{\hspace{4.2pt}This lower footnote [yyyyyyyyy gggggggg] does not clear the frame boundary}

\clearpage

Another page.

\end{document}


To me, it appears that the baseline of the lowest footnote text is exactly on the lower boundary of the body frame, which is what I would expect.

The line surely strikes through the "y"s and "g"s.  Can the line be lowered or the text raised just a little?

It does strike through the descenders of the letters, right. But descenders always extend below the baseline. So, as I said, this is what I would expect. If you lower the lower border of the body frame, the baseline would also shift along. You could add some vertical space after the footnote maybe, but I can't really see why you would like to do that.

(... assuming that you don't want to print the text frame.)

That is exactly what I had in mind. I would like to experiment with having a light frame to appear as a border on every page.

You can add \strut\hrule height0pt to the end of a footnote.  This moves the baseline to the bottom.  The \strut is in case this is NOT the last footnote on the page.

Tried \strut\hrule height after the last character in text of each footnote; it had the opposite effect, So I tried \vspace{2.4pt} - it moved the text upwards; is there any hidden downside to doing this?
